# Unjustified pattern match may not be exhaustive warning

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, compiler-warnings, case-class

During learning I have came across warning I believe to be unjustified.
I have separated code snippet to demonstrate it.

So to put it in a nutshell I have:

1. Sealed trait to allow exhaustive matching by compiler

```
sealed trait Shape {
  def sides: Int
  def perimeter: Double
  def area: Double
  def colour: Colour
}
```

2. Final case class implementations also for exhaustive matching

```
sealed trait Rectangular extends Shape {
  override def sides: Int = 4
  override def perimeter: Double = 2 * width + 2 * height
  override def area: Double = width * height
  def width: Double
  def height: Double
}
```

```
case class Circle(radius: Double, colour: Colour) extends Shape {
  override def perimeter: Double = 2.0 * math.Pi * radius
  override def area: Double = math.Pi * radius * radius
  override val sides: Int = 0
}
```

```
case class Square(sideLength: Double, colour: Colour) extends Rectangular {
  val width = sideLength
  val height = sideLength
}
```

3. And finally a pattern match(of course logic after => is simplified, because matching is what matters):

```
case object Draws {
  def apply(shape: Shape): String = shape match {
    case Square(_, predef) => predef.toString
    case Rectangle(_, _, predef) => predef.toString
    case Circle(_, predef) => predef.toString
  }
}
```

And I am really shocked by the warning:

```
match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following inputs: Circle(_, _), Rectangle(_, _, _), Square(_, _), _
def apply(shape: Shape): String = shape match {
```

From what I understand, my match covers cases like `Circle(_, _)` - i just bind last attribute to predef variable. Also case _ should be covered since I exhaust all possibilities.

Could anyone help me with any explanation why in particular this could be end in a MatchError? I can't figure it out myself.

With regards,
Michael

Comment: I can't test right now, but for what I could see you are right. Is the error real? Some editors like **IntelliJ** tend to produce false errors, have you compiled the code using a real compiler? Can you create a reproducible example in **Scastie**?

Comment: I have tested this in Scastie(nice tool by the way, thanks) as you suggested and no warning is produced, so I guess that's an IntelliJ issue. 

Do you have any solutions for such issues in editors?
Do you recommend other editors for scala?

Comment: Full scastie example if anyone wonders:
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/8L23xSPBT2uIYxDYRILTNQ

Comment: No idea what could be done in **IntelliJ**, I never used due this reason. The community in general seems to be happy with it despite this problems. - I personally use **vscode** + **metals** which ensures all the highlights are real; the downside is that it is more tricky to install and setup than a simple install _(although is not rocket engineering neither)_ and is way more minimalist, but I like that.

Comment: My 2020.2 intelij isn't complaining. A side remark, I wouldn't use `predef` for naming anything to avoid confusion as it's already used in Scala: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/Predef$.html